# Creating Python 3.4 Environment in Anaconda

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda

I have Python 2.7 Anaconda 64 bit on Windows 7.

I want to create a Python 3.4 environment. So at the command I typed:

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

I get the following problems

```
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
```

it then runs through all the packages and gives another error:

```
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/menuinst-1.0.4-py34_0.tar.bz2
Error: Connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590): https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/fre
e/win-64/menuinst-1.0.4-py34_0.tar.bz2
```

Then of course when I type

```
activate py34
```

I get:

```
No environment named "py34" exists in C:\Users\martbar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\envs
```

any ideas what could be the issue? I am on a corporate PC but when I looked at the firewall on my PC it said it was off.

Comment: Did you create Virtual env like `python.exe -m py34`. If yes, then set the PATH to your Windows environment variable 
`set PATH=C:\Anaconda\envs\py34\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\envs\py34;%PATH%`

And Then Activate as `activate py34`

Comment: That doesn't really affect it not connecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying connection to `https://repo.continuum.io` is not passing a certificate verification test. You can go there in your browser to see if your OS may be missing this certificate. If so, then run Windows Update and look for a "Update for Root Certificates for Windows 7" entry that you can install.